# Swift: Replacing sqlite file fails

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite

I am working on an App for iPhone and I try to develop a backup function for my sqlite database to the users dropbox:

If the user is doing a (manual) backup, my file „myDatabase.sqlite3“ is copied to a selected folder in the dropbox.

If the user imports the backup, I am replacing the „myDatabase.sqlite3“ file with the one from the dropbox. After this, all Selects on the database fail with the error „[logging] disk I/O error in „SELECT…“. BUT if I restart my app, everything works great!

So I think it’s something missing with the connection (of course I opened a new connection after replacing the file)? Maybe something isn’t refreshed or rebuild? What am I missing? I don’t have these *-shm and *-wal files I read about in some tutorials.

Thanks a lot for your help, I have spent hours and days trying everything I could find…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the mistake: it was a timing problem... I opened the new connection while the copy process hasn't finished!